# Combining scatterplots

Tags: r, layout, scatter-plot, r-car, cowplot

I am trying to combine multiple (four) scatter plots into one figure (but not a scatterplot matrix). I am making the individual scatter plots with the `scatterplot()` function of the `car` package. I used to be able to combine the four plots using either the `layout()` or `par()` function. However, now when I try to do this in Rstudio, it just displays the four plots sequentially. I'm not sure if this is because of the newer versions of R or Rstudio.

Here is an example using the mtcars dataset:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), oma=c(1,1,2,1), mar=c(4,4,0,1), cex.lab=1, cex.axis=0.8)

scatterplot(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="", ylab="mpg", grid=F)

scatterplot(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="", ylab="", grid=F)

scatterplot(hp ~ disp, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="hp", ylab="mpg", grid=F)

scatterplot(hp ~ wt, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="Weight", ylab="", grid=F)
```

I am running R 3.4.2, RStudio 1.1.453, on Windows 10. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`plot_grid`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html) from `cowplot` package. Note that `cowplot` requires `R 3.5.0`.

Edit: to clarify, you need the development version of `cowplot` on GitHub

```
devtools::install_github("wilkelab/cowplot")

library(car)
library(gridGraphics)
library(cowplot)

par(xpd = NA, # switch off clipping, necessary to always see axis labels
    bg = "transparent", # switch off background to avoid obscuring adjacent plots
    oma = c(1, 1, 2, 1), 
    mar = c(4, 4, 0, 1),
    mgp = c(2, 1, 0), # move axis labels closer to axis
    cex.lab  = 1, 
    cex.axis = 0.8
) 

scatterplot(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="", ylab="mpg", grid=F)
rec1 <- recordPlot()  # record the previous plot

scatterplot(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="", ylab="", grid=F)
rec2 <- recordPlot()

scatterplot(hp ~ disp, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="hp", ylab="mpg", grid=F)
rec3 <- recordPlot()

scatterplot(hp ~ wt, data=mtcars, smooth=F, boxplots=F, xlab="Weight", ylab="", grid=F)
rec4 <- recordPlot()

plot_grid(rec1, rec2, rec3, rec4,
          labels = "AUTO", 
          hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This works reliably only with the development version of cowplot (0.9.99, which requires R 3.5.0), not with the one currently on CRAN (0.9.2, which doesn't require R 3.5.0).